# Simple pdf viewer using UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have a problem.
I'm trying to make a simple app to view pdfs with an `UIPageViewController` but I can't get it working.

I tried to use the project listed on the github page below.

https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF

But I'm used to work with `StoryBoards` but I cant get it working with `StoryBoards`.

I created a button with the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mhm" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
[self presentViewController:page animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PageViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PDFPageViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I remove the last two lines, my project is working but as you can imagine my pdf doesn't show up.

I tried creating separate views in my storyboard, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: did you add the QuartzCore framework to your app project?

Comment: @JonathanD yes I did, I juist followed all the steps of the github page. It works without storyboards, but with storyboards it dienst. Do hou have an idea? It is caused by the last two lines

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mhm" ofType:@"pdf"];
    UIPageViewController *page = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
    [self presentViewController:page animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try this one

Comment: UIPageViewController is generic and it's used to show a group of view controllers as a book. And of course, it doesn't contain a method takes a PDF directly.